# What goes into Spring Security's ACL_OBJECT_IDENTITY table?

Tags: java, spring-security, acl

I'm attempting to integrate Spring Security with ACL support into an existing GWT application, and if I click another unhelpful link I swear will need a new mouse and keyboard. I've worked through what will be needed to use Spring to authenticate against Active Directory via LDAP, and I've worked out how we can assign custom permissions based on AD attributes (i.e. group membership), and I've even worked out how to perform a custom check against permissions (a true bitmask operation) using a custom ACL schema. What I haven't figured out is just what goes into the ACL tables.

**ACL_SID**

```
id:bigint (pk)
principal:boolean (ak)
sid:varchar (ak)
```

This table is pretty self-explanatory; we'll be using non-principal entries here only.

**ACL_CLASS**

```
id:bigint (pk)
class:varchar (ak)
```

This table is also pretty self-explanatory. As I understand it, we simply create an entry for every class/interface we wish to secure.

**ACL_ENTRY**

```
id:bigint (pk)
acl_object_identity:bigint (fak)
ace_order:int (ak)
sid:bigint (fk)
mask:bigint
granting:boolean
audit_success:boolean
audit_failure:boolean
```

This table is also mostly self-explanatory; we've customized the schema with a bigint/long in the `mask` field, but the question stems from just what `acl_object_identity` is referencing. Obviously, it points to the field in `ACL_OBJECT_IDENTITY`, but...

**ACL_OBJECT_IDENTITY**

```
id:bigint (pk)
object_id_class:bigint (fak)
object_id_identity:bigint (ak)
parent_object_identity:bigint (fk)
owner_sid:bigint (fk)
entries_inheriting:boolean
```

The `object_id_identity` is, what? A method? How is it referenced by way of Spring Security's annotations?

**MyClass.java**

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#someInput, 'READ')")
public boolean myMethod(String someInput) {
    return true;
}
```

Presumably, `#someInput` refers somehow to the `ACL_OBJECT_IDENTITY.object_id_identity` field, but how?

Answer (score 1):

First you need some kind of domain object class to store your data. This class must have a `getId()` method. For example:

```
public class DomainObject {
    private Long id;
    private String data;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Change your secured method to:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#someInput, 'READ')")
public boolean myMethod(DomainObject someInput) {
    return true;
}
```

Now, `someInput.getId()` is the same as `ACL_OBJECT_IDENTITY.object_id_identity`.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the [Grails Spring Security ACL Plugin Documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-acl/docs/manual/guide/2.%20Usage.html#2.3%20Domain%20Classes).
It explains the domain classes used for the specific plugin, but it might help you. Look for AclObjectIdentity and AbstractAclObjectIdentity.

The ACL_OBJECT_IDENTITY.object_id_identity field is the instance id and uniquely identify the instance (together with object_id_class)

In your example, 'someInput' would be that instance.
this piece of code is taken from the beforementioned documentation:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#report, delete) or hasPermission(#report, admin)")
void deleteReport(Report report) {
    report.delete()
}
```

It explains itself immo. The report is deleted if the currently authenticated user has permission 'admin' or 'delete' for the given Report instance. Report is someInput in your code snippet.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to suggest a slight misunderstanding of Spring ACL. In the question, we are asked how to register an ACL for a `String` object, so that this method protection will work:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#someInput, 'READ')")
public boolean myMethod(String someInput) {
    return true;
}
```

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16441728/5134722), it doesn't really make sense to protect a `String` object. When you think about it, this makes sense. Loosely speaking, we can divide all objects into two categories:

1. Objects that are persisted to the DB - let's call them entities
2. Objects that are not persisted to the DB - let's call them transients

In any real-life use case I can think of, it only makes sense to protect access to an entity, not a transient; I'll argue for this case in general later. To start with though, let's stick with a use case related to that of the question to see why protection of a transient probably isn't what's desired in this case.

#### Use Case

It's not 100% clear what the use case is in the question e.g. what `someInput` represents. But I'm assuming the use case is similar to the following. Suppose there are `BankAccount` entities and some operation on those entities e.g. `readAccount`. Only users who have read access to a `BankAccount` should be allowed to call `readAccount`. Now, `BankAccount` entities may be uniquely identifiable by their `accountNumber`, which is of type `String`. So we may be mistakenly led to try something like this, which is similar to the code in the question:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#accountNumber, 'READ')")
public Account readAccount(String accountNumber) {
    //CODE THAT RETRIEVES THE ENTITY FROM THE DB AND RETURNS IT
}
```

OK, it's not a bad assumption to make. I suppose the idea in our minds at this stage is that Spring ACL stores a table of account numbers, and for each account number, a list of people who have READ access to it. The problem is, Spring ACL doesn't work like that. As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16441728/5134722), Spring ACL identifies an objects in the following way:

1. What is the class of the object? In this case, it would be `java.lang.String`
2. What is the ID of the object? In this case, Spring ACL requires that the object needs a `getId()` method. Luckily, if you're using Hibernate, all your entities will have this by default, so you don't need to do anything extra to implement it. But what about String? Well, this doesn't have a `getId()` method. So Spring ACL won't be able to register an ACL for it and you won't be able to set up any permissions for Strings.

When you think about it, it actually makes sense that Spring ACL is designed this way. The `getId()` method allows us to associate the persisted ACL permissions entries with the persisted entities. This is the typical use case. So in the above example, what we're really trying to do is restrict access to `Account` objects, not account numbers. In that case, we have two options: preauthorize or postuathorize.

With pre-authorize, we'd need the fully-qualified path to the `Account` class. So let's say it's in the package `X.Y`, we'd have:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#accountId, 'X.Y.Account', 'READ')")
public Account readAccount(Long accountId) {
    //CODE THAT RETRIEVES THE ENTITY FROM THE DB AND RETURNS IT
}
```

Notice that in the above, we are using the ID, not the account number, to identify the account. This is the only way you are allowed identify an entity with Spring ACL, because the `getId()` is the link between the ACLs and their associated objects. Of course, you're free to write whatever code you like to retrieve the object by the given ID e.g. you could do something silly like increment the ID before retrieving it. So the object returned isn't guaranteed to be the same one that's authorized in this case: that's up to you to write the correct retrieval code.

The other way we can protect the method is with post authorize, as follows:

```
@PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, 'READ')")
public Account readAccount(String accountNumber) {
    //CODE THAT RETRIEVES THE ENTITY FROM THE DB AND RETURNS IT
}
```

In this case, the code that retrieves the account entity is actually called, and then only after it's retrieved, the account, which is the object returned, is checked by the ACL framework against the current user and the READ permission. An advantage here is that we can retrieve the account any way we like e.g. by `accountNumber` in this case. Another advantage is that the object that's authorized is guaranteed to be the same as the one returned. The disadvantage is that we have to actually do the retrieval before we can make the call as to whether the user has permission or not. And if they don't have permission, then the retrieved object is effectively thrown away and so it may be a bit less performant than `@PreAuthorize` if the retrieval code is expensive to run.

#### Why Protecting Strings with Spring ACL Doesn't Make Sense Anyway

Technically speaking, I suppose you might be able to protect Strings, or indeed any other transient as long as it has a `getId()` method. With Strings, we could maybe add an extension function `getId()` for example. But I can't think of a practical use case for why we'd want to do that. For example, imagine we not only have `Account` objects but we also have `Customer` objects. And let's say `Customer` objects are uniquely identifiable by a `customerNumber` field, which is a `String`. And suppose we want to restrict access to customers in a similar way to accounts. Then what if coincidentally a `customerNumber` matched an `accountNumber`? In Spring ACL, we are only allowed one entry in the object identity table for every combination of object class plus ID, as per the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-schema.html):

```
CONSTRAINT uk_acl_object_identity UNIQUE (object_id_class, object_id_identity)
```

So, suppose the `String` `"fadfads389"` happens to be both a `customerNumber` for some `Customer` and an `accountNumber` for some `Account`. If we were to restrict access to it via Spring ACL, what would that mean? Would it mean that a user has access to the account? The customer? Both?

Hopefully this example demonstrates why it doesn't really make sense to protect some transient class such as `String` with Spring ACL when that transient is used to identify entities: when we're interested in protecting entities we just protect the entities themselves, using the implicit ID of those entities e.g. the ID stored by Hibernate.

#### Transients Could Still be protected

Of course, there's nothing stopping you from adding object identity entries into the Spring ACL `acl_object_identity` table for any class you want, as long as that class has a `getId()` method. So it is certainly possible for you to add permissions relating to transients, and should those transients appear again in memory then Spring ACL will kick in. But this isn't really what Spring ACL was designed for - it's really meant to protect entities, not transients, which are linked to the ACL logic by `getId()`.

#### Strings Could Still be Used in PreAuthorize

Now, although we shouldn't really use *Spring ACL* to protect `String`s, that's not to say that `@PreAuthorize` is completely off the table when it comes to `Strings`. We note that `@PreAuthorize` can handle *any* [SpEL](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language) expression, the same for `@PostAuthorize` and the other method annotations as pointed out [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security). So, for example, you would be able to do something like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("#user.accountNumbers.contains(#accountNumber)")
public Account readAccount(String accountNumber, User user) {
    //CODE THAT RETRIEVES THE ENTITY FROM THE DB AND RETURNS IT
}
```

The above assumes that the `User` class maintains a list of account numbers to which that user has access, so presumably a `User` is an entity, or at least is backed by some DB-persisted data.

However, beware if you do want to go down this path. Not only do you risk entangling your access control logic with the rest of your business logic, you also might lose out on the performance front; Spring ACL uses caching to make permissions lookups fast whereas the above code presumably needs to fetch `User` data from the DB in order to do the authorization.